# C++ & GDI+ Changing bar value + string on this bar - live - string imposes

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

This is my WM_PAINT:

```
    case WM_PAINT:

    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
```

to drawstring on bar i'm using this func:

```
void drawstr(HWND okno, char * msg, int fontsize, std::wstring font, Color color){
    Font myFont(font.c_str(), fontsize);
    PointF origin(20.0f, 0.0f);
    Graphics* graphics = Graphics::FromHWND(okno);

    SolidBrush blackBrush(color);

    size_t buffer = strlen(msg)+1;
    wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[strlen(msg) + 1];
    mbstowcs_s(&buffer,wc, buffer, msg, strlen(msg) + 1);
        graphics->DrawString(wc, (int) buffer, &myFont, origin, &blackBrush);

    delete graphics;

}
```

This func drawstr , draw string per ~ 400 ms , value of the drawed str is changing and the result is:

[image]

And You can see, that when i'm changing value the string overlap. If i value dont change, string overlap too , but it seems thicker (bar 2 and 3)

I try with func : `invalidaterect` but i dont know where it should be.

Comment: You need to redraw the background of the bar before drawing the text over the top of it.

Comment: with invalidaterect(window,null,TRUE) ?

Comment: That will mark your window as needing painting, but you still need code to actually do the painting...

Comment: Hmm, sorry man. But i really dont understand how to do it

Comment: I make `InvalidateRect(window, NULL, TRUE);`

before sendmessage ( to set pos of progress bar)
and drawstring

Its nearly, but sometimes i see that bar and string disappears (~for 0,5 S ) but its visible.

If i make invalidaterect, before sendmessage and drawstr for 3 bars , text + bar is visible only on first bar...

Comment: You should be painting inside your `WM_PAINT` handler. The string is disappearing because the `BeginPaint` function erases the background, and you don't draw anything before calling `EndPaint`.